# R: Which element of a list corresponds to an element of a sorted list

Tags: r, list

If I have a vector x, and I want to know which 5 values of x have the smallest values and their location in x.

The smallest 5 values of x will be sort(x)[1:5],

But how do I know what place these values have in the original x vector?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `order` function.

> order returns a permutation which rearranges its first argument into ascending or descending order, breaking ties by further arguments. sort.list is the same, using only one argument.

```
> x <- rnorm(10)
[1]  1.6722546  1.3608374  0.7912174 -0.7017244 -0.2093535  1.7224396 -0.9370661 -1.5226014  0.4416517 -0.0455294
> order(x)
[1]  8  7  4  5 10  9  3  2  1  6
> x[order(x)[1:3]]
[1] -1.5226014 -0.9370661 -0.7017244
```